# Sort Filelist, Folders then Files, both alphabetically in Android

Tags: android, sorting, comparator, filelist

In my Android App I have a fileList and sort it with this:

```
Collections.sort(fileList, new ItemFileNameComparator());
```

To sort this list alphabetically I use the following code:

```
    private class ItemFileNameComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
    return lhs.file.toLowerCase(Locale.GERMAN).compareTo(rhs.file.toLowerCase(Locale.GERMAN));
    }
}
```

But this sorts all items alphabetically, I want to have folders first sorted alphabetically, then files sorted alphabetically.
Is there a way to do this?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please post more code, for example the source of Item class, we cannot help you without knowing nothing about implementation about the object to compare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the variable file of Item is string. If so you have to change it to File as shown. If not you may not need converting string to file.

```
private static class ItemFileNameComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
        File lhsFile = new File(lhs.file.toLowerCase(Locale.GERMAN));
        File rhsFile= new File( rhs.file.toLowerCase(Locale.GERMAN));

        String lhsDir = lhsFile.isDirectory()? lhsFile.getPath() : lhsFile.getParent();
        String rhsDir = rhsFile.isDirectory()? rhsFile.getPath() : rhsFile.getParent();

        int result =  lhsDir.toLowerCase().compareTo(rhsDir .toLowerCase());    

        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }else{              
            if(lhsFile.isDirectory()!= rhsFile.isDirectory()){
                return lhsFile.getParent().toLowerCase().compareTo( rhsFile.getParent().toLowerCase());
            }
            return lhsFile.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo( rhsFile.getName().toLowerCase());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I also figured the Item was just containing the file name :

```
private class ItemFileNameComparator implements Comparator<File>{
    public int compare(Item lhsS, Item rhsS){
        File lhs = new File(lhsS.file.toLowerCase(Locale.GERMAN));
        File rhs= new File(rhsS.file.toLowerCase(Locale.GERMAN));
        if (lhs.isDirectory() && !rhs.isDirectory()){
            // Directory before File
            return -1;
        } else if (!lhs.isDirectory() && rhs.isDirectory()){
            // File after directory
            return 1;  
        } else {
            // Otherwise in Alphabetic order...
            return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
        }
    }
}
```